# Accented URL in Facebook page information

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm trying to setting up a page in Facebook, but when inserting the website URL (`www.associazionecreattività.it`) Facebook tells me that it is not valid; same thing for the email address.

I think that it is because of the accent, but how can I write the URL correctly?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "setting"?  It's not apparent from the context.

Comment: I mean setting up, sorry. Edited

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: http://www.xn--associazionecreattivit-z2b.it/ try this one friend

Comment: Yes, this works. Is the only way?

Answer (score -2):

Update:

You say that you've purchased  the URL from a domain registrar - but if i go to that URL, it redirects to http://www.xn--associazionecreattivit-z2b.it/

If that is the correct behaviour, then you should quote http://www.xn--associazionecreattivit-z2b.it   as the URL.

(Background:   it seems that Italian registrars have found a way to sell URLs with accents, but fundamentally URLs can only have standard ASCII characters.  At the current time.  Ref:   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: I've already bought the url, if you try to go to that url (www.associazionecreattività.it), the website is up